# char not registered in while loop

Tags: c, input, while-loop

I don't understand why my while loop doesn't find a # when i input #. I want the loop to break out when I input # under `Enter name:` so `e.name` will have `#`.

When I try it, the loop never ends however `e.name` will contain `#`

```
int readin(Employee *p)
{   Employee e = *p;
    int count = 0;
    while(e.name[0] != "#"){
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        scanf("\n");
        gets(e.name);
        printf("Enter tel:\n");
        scanf("\n");
        scanf("%s", &e.telno);
        printf("Enter id:\n");
        scanf("\n");
        scanf("%d", &e.id);
        printf("Enter salary:\n");
        scanf("\n");
        scanf("%lf" , &e.salary);
    }
    *p = e;
}
```

Comment: `e.name[0] != "#"`->`e.name[0] != '#'`. Don't use `gets` use `fgets` instead. `scanf("%s", &e.telno);` -> `scanf("%s", e.telno);` (I guess best). meaning of `scanf("\n");`.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings which will warn about `while(e.name[0] != "#"){` faster than posting on stack-overflow.

Comment: So a complete example with structure definition etc. I would be able to help.

Comment: Would you put a complete example? It would help me.

Answer (score 1):

In your while statement:

```
while(e.name[0] != "#")
```

You are comparing a character to a pointer.  The pointer is the memory address of the string "#".  You have to change your code to:

```
while(e.name[0] != '#')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems, but this should get you started,  It can sometimes be challenging making sure all white space (space, newline, tabs, etc) is consumed.

```
// My guess at employee structure
typedef struct
{
    char name[100];
    char telno[25];
    int id;
    double salary;
} Employee;

// NOTE: MSVC "forces" me to use safe version of some funtions: "_s" suffix

int readin(Employee *p)
{
    Employee e = *p;
    int count = 0; // <-- Never used

    char line[80];

    // Why are you looping, you only ever modify 1 employee?
    while (e.name[0] != '#') // <- Fixed comparison
    {
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        //scanf("\n"); <- Not needed
        gets_s(e.name);
        //*Test for '#' here and exit loop before entering other fields?

        printf("Enter tel:\n");
        //scanf("\n"); <- Not needed
        //scanf_s("%s", &e.telno, 25);
        gets_s(e.telno, 25);

        printf("Enter id:\n");
        //scanf("\n"); <- Not needed
        //scanf_s("%d", &e.id);
        //*scanf leaves trailing white (newline), I usually prefer gets/sscanf combination
        gets_s(line, sizeof(line));
        sscanf_s(line, "%d", &e.id);

        printf("Enter salary:\n");
        //scanf("\n"); <- Not needed
        //scanf_s("%lf", &e.salary);
        //*scanf leaves trailing white (newline), I usually prefer gets/sscanf combination
        gets_s(line, sizeof(line)); // 
        sscanf_s(line, "%lf", &e.salary);
    }

    *p = e;

    return 0; // <- Added, function declared to return an int, what do you want to return?
}
```